# Question about "not differ from each other by much more than"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I want to make sure that my understanding of the sentence below is accurate:

> The ages of white pines in a certain forest do not differ from each other by much more than the length of time it takes a white pine to grow to maturity.

My understanding:

> The ages of those pines differ from each other not more than the maturity time of a white pine.

Comment: Suppose it takes the trees 10 years to grow to maturity. The trees were all planted within a period of about 10 years.

Comment: Thank you, Weather!